# REDHAWK - Failed to configure component

Tags: redhawksdr

I have a waveform used to demodulate a signal received on an RTL device.  Someone else created the waveform using REDHAWK 1.8.3 and it works fine for him.  I am running REDHAWK 1.9 in a CentOS 6.3 virtual machine.  I have reconfigured and rebuilt everything.  When that did not work, I regenerated everything for 1.9 and rebuilt again and had the same result.  I am able start the domain manager and device manager without error.  When I try to instantiate an instance of the waveform, I get the following:

```
WARNING: Unable to set bandwidth.
INFO:RTLRDC_i - Allocated [FRONTEND::tuner_allocation] RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER, 0 to MC_Frontend
ERROR:PropertySet_impl - Setting property control failed.  Cause: Unable to set value
ERROR:ApplicationFactory_impl - Failed to 'configure' component: 'MultiDemod' with component id: 'MultiDemod_1:MCWaveform_1 assigned to device: 'DCE:539804f4-37cc-426f-8dd0-3128d866981e'  in waveform 'MCWaveform_1';InvalidConfiguration with this info: <No matching properties found> for these invalid properties: (control,Kind: 21) error occurred near line:3251 in file:ApplicationFactory_impl.cpp;
INFO:RTLRDC_i - Deallocated [FRONTEND::tuner_allocation] RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER, 0 for MC_Frontend
ERROR:ApplicationFactory_impl - Error in application creation; Configure of component failed (unclear where in the process this occurred)
```

The 'control' property does exist on the component.  Does anyone have any thoughts on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control property is a struct.  One of the fields in the struct did not have an initial value set.  This was not an issue for REDHAWK 1.8.3 but caused the above error for REDHAWK 1.9.  The solution was to make sure that all parameters for the struct had an initial value.